# How to use javac -h?

Tags: java, javac, javah

The new feature of java 10, which removed `javah`, instead providing `javac -h`. But when I tried this, it said "No source file". I try to add source file name, class file name, class file name(no suffix), dir name, ... in tail, but it's no use. And I can find the help from google, the pages all teach how to use `javah`.